# window always on top using xlib

Tags: c, linux, xlib, gtk2

I'm in the process of creating a gtk2 application which I would like drawn over all other apps at all times, I would rather use xlib to do that if it is possible

here's my code so far:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        GtkWidget     *mainwin;
        mainwin = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_widget_show_all (mainwin);
        gtk_main ();
        return 0;
}
```

I'd like to do this in the simplest manner possible
thanks

Comment: I think there's an event you can catch when part of the window gets obscured. When you get that even you could always put your window at the front. Not that I recommend it, or having an always front window, it disrupts many peoples work-flow. I personally *hate* windows that puts themselves in front of the window I need to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and not complicated

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  GtkWidget     *mainwin;
  mainwin = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_keep_above ( (GtkWindow *) mainwin, TRUE);
  gtk_widget_show_all (mainwin);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

gtk_window_set_keep_above does trick if window manager is cooperative.

Comment: Wonderful, just wonderful didn't think it would be that simple

Comment: To compile that code: `gcc window.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0) -o window` (or also with 3.0 instead of 2.0).